# Adjacency to transposed edgelist in igraph in R

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I have a relatively large 2 mode network in adjacency matrix form of 4000 rows and 9000 columns I'm interested in looking at the relationships between the columns.

With a smaller network I would do `t(matrix) %*% matrix`, however I think a 9000^2 matrix would max out the memory on my computer.

One option is to convert the igraph adjacency matrix to the sna pacakge format, and use `sna::gt`, but I was wondering if there was similar functionality in igraph?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`graph.incidence`](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=igraph%3agraph.incidence) to construct the bipartite graph from your adjacency matrix, and then use [`bipartite.projection`](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=igraph%3abipartite.projection) to project it to the corresponding one-mode network, based on either the rows or the columns.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the `bipartite.projection` command (obviously).